# Unable to fetch data from Mysql DB until I manually restart the server

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, pymysql

I am putting some data on db in one tab of my application then unable to fetch the same data in another tab of the appilcation.
I then restarted my server then it showed up.

```
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pranj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 775, in after_cancel
    data = self.tk.call('after', 'info', id)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

on cntrl+c this error gets displayed

Comment: This error is from tkinter. What is that doing in a Django application?

Comment: I have uninstalled tkinter but stll the error exists @DanielRoseman                    
 pip uninstall tkinter
WARNING: Skipping tkinter as it is not installed.

Comment: Well you can't uninstall tkinter, it's part of the standard library. But that wasn't what I said to do, anyway. I wanted to know why you are calling tkinter in the first place.

Comment: earlier I used the save file dialog box of tkinter but now have removed the use of it @DanielRoseman

Comment: @DanielRoseman any idea on what to do